Is there a way to make Meld automatically open a blank 2-file comparison?
When I use Meld, usually I'm copy-pasting content from websites and so I want to do a blank 2-file comparison. The thing is, every time, I have to click File comparison then Blank comparison. Can I just have it do that automatically when it starts?
Research

I checked the settings but didn't see anything like "on startup".
I checked the Keyboard shortcuts section of the help (F1), but the closest one is Start a new comparison (Ctrl+N), which is exactly where I was.
I checked the user manual:

§ Getting started comparing files - All it says is "You can start a new file comparison using the new comparison button on the toolbar."

§ Command line usage - It says: "For a two- or three-way file comparison, start Meld with meld file1 file2"
So I tried meld '' '', but it started a folder comparison on the working directory.
I also tried meld - -, hoping that would work sort of like cat -, but it just errors that the file - can't be opened.

§ Things that Meld doesn't do - This isn't listed there.




Remarks
I suppose if I wanted to make a feature request, meld '' '' should be changed to do what I want, and if you want a folder comparison on the working directory, use meld . .

Until the merge request gets merged (see previous answer), this is what I'd do:
meld $(mktemp) $(mktemp)

This would create two empty tmpfiles (in /tmp with random names) and open them side-by-side.

This is a great workaround! I'd love it even more if the two filenames were similar. Is there a way to have mktemp create files of the form like tmp.XXX.0 and tmp.XXX.1 where XXX is the same?

What I ended up doing is creating a temp dir then touching files inside it for Meld, like this: d=$(mktemp -d); touch "$d"/{0,1}; meld "$d"/{0,1}

A maintainer added the command line argument @blank, so what I want would be meld @blank @blank, but this change hasn't been published yet - latest version Meld 3.22.
